JSON validation fails with binary file in Python
I'm trying to validate a JSON with a binary file.
def upload_image(self, image_path, title, description):
        self.collection = self.db["images"]
        with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
            image_binary = image_file.read()

        document = {
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "image": image_binary
        }
        if Util.validate_json(document, self.schema):
            print("JSON data is valid")
            res = super().insert('images', document)
        else:
            print("JSON data is not valid")

My schema looks like this
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "description": {"type": "string"},
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "binary"
        }
    },
    "required": ["title", "description", "image"]
}

As far as I understand, the binary file is converted in a base64 string. I also tried "type": "object" or without '"format"' but still get a JSON not valid error. Any ideas what I could try?
I tried "type": "object" or without '"format"'. I didn't find an example in the documentation.

Why would the binary file be converted to a string?
